# Managing memory in tree traversing Lua function

Tags: memory, recursion, lua, tree, genetic-algorithm

I have two algorithms for returning a random node in a tree where a node can have 0-N children (current node is `node`, node's first child is `node[1]` etc.). The first algorithm, uniform selection, chooses a random node uniformly from the tree. It stores a node to be returned, as it moves down the tree this node is replaced with the node it is currently at with probability 1/(number of nodes seen so far). Lua code below.

```
function uniformSelect(node)
    local chosen = node

    function choose(node, counter)
        counter = counter + 1
        local probability = 1/counter
        if math.random() < probability then
            chosen = node
        end

        for i = 1, node.arity do
            choose(node[i], counter)
        end
    end

    choose(node, 0)
    return chosen
end
```

The second algorithm moves down the tree,  looking at the node it is currently on and returns it with a given probability P. If this node is not returned then the probability of moving to the node's children is P1, P2 ... PN which add up to 1. Lua code below.

```
function select(node, prob)
    local r = math.random()
    if r < prob or node.arity == 0 then
        return node
    end

    local p = {}
    if node.arity == 1 then
        table.insert(p, 1)
    else
        local total = count(node) -- total number of nodes below this one
        for i = 1, node.arity do
            -- insert probability of moving to child i into p
            table.insert(p, (count(node[i])+1)/total)
        end

    end
    -- move to a child node chosen by roulette wheel selection
    return select(node[roulette(p)], prob)
end
```

These algorithms are used in a genetic programming framework. When I use the first algorithm, the uniform selection, it first works fine in terms of speed and memory. The second one however cannot be used with large populations over many generations, the memory it uses explodes. I've graphed this memory growth below, the blue line "prob" is the second algorithm, `select`.

[image: Memory Use]

To me, `select` looks like it is tail recursive. I've also tried explicitly calling the garbage collector to see if that helps, it slows the growth down slightly but the growth is still massive.

Can anyone tell me what causes this difference?

Comment: What happens if you grab a value from p and store it in a local [local rand_idx = roulette( p )], then wipe p, before you call the recursive select( node[rand_idx], prob)? I have a suspicion that your recursion is leaving a reference to p laying about which, in turn, would prevent the garbage collector from cleaning it up?

Comment: Does `roulette` maybe store something globally?

Comment: `uniformSelect` is very non-random.  The last branch of the root node has much greater chances than the first branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I graphed the average depths of the trees being produced and found the answer. The crossover operation with the `select` function increases the average depth of the trees in the population, causing the program to slow down and use much more memory.

[image]

Comment: I won't delete this post immediately in case it's useful to anybody, but if I should delete it, please let me know.

Comment: I'd still like to reiterate what I pointed out in my prior comment... what happens if you wipe the p table before you recurse? Allocating local tables inside of loops, methods and especially recursion will bite you every time if you don't make sure you're cleaning them up.

Comment: I did an experiment to check this and you're absolutely right, the P table leaves a hefty footprint unless it's freed. Explicitly calling the garbage collector improves the situation but freeing the P table certainly helps. You might be interested to see the [graphs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bw2e1MVuxECbX0wtc1o3TzRoSW8/edit?usp=sharing) produced.

Comment: That's pretty much what I expected to see. Use of temporary tables inside of functions, loops, etc., it devastating to performance. A lesson I learned the hard way myself ~smile~ Hopefully that little tip will help you going forward. For the record, if you do further testing, you'll likely find that explicitly calling the GC will carry a very heavy penalty, too. If you let the GC run when it has free cycles and just make sure you keep the temporary tables under control, you'll likely achieve the result you're after.